# JavaScript Closures and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, closures, settimeout

Closures are something I still don't fully grasp in JS. I think this is a closure issue. I'm trying to create a progress bar. Every x seconds I want to increment the width of a DIV. Here's the part that is supposed to do that:

```
for(i=0;i<=counter;i++){
    setTimeout(function (){
        myDiv.style.width = wIncrement+"px"
        timeIncrement++;
        wIncrement++;
    },timeIncrement*1000);
}
```

What I want to happen is every x seconds, increase the size of the bar. If course, that's not what's happening.

I'm pretty sure (hope) that this is a closure issue, but the syntax to mix with a setTimout completely flummoxes me. Can anyone help me grasp the concepts needed to fix the closure issue in this example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing is that you're incrementing a `timeIncrement` inside closure. So effectively you do not increment it **at all** until first timeout happens. Here is the changed code:

```
for(i=0;i<=counter;i++){
    setTimeout(function (){
        myDiv.style.width = wIncrement+"px"
        wIncrement++;
    }, i*1000);
}
```

You still might have issues with `wIncrement` variable. Also I would use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` for this reason.

Comment: ah! So I have to use a variable from the for to increment the timeout (rather than an internal variable). This works! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `setTimeout` you want to use `setInterval`.  The latter will call the function once per interval instead of just once.

```
var width = 50
setInternal(function () {
  myDiv.style.width = width
  width++
  }, timeIncrement * 1000);
```

Additionally at some point you'll probably want to end the interval and stop incrementing the size.  For that you'll need to call `clearInterval` on the result of `setInterval`

```
var width = 50
var t = setInterval(function () {
  myDiv.style.width = width
  width++
  if (doneIncrementing) {
    clearInterval(t);
  }
  }, timeIncrement * 1000);
```

Comment: @mVChr thought so too but they didn't mention it should complete ever.  I'll update with an answer that demonstrates this anyways

Comment: When I run the latter, I get a setInternal is not defined.

Comment: @DA it's because I can't spell.  It should be `setInterval` instead of `setInternal`.  I've corrected my answer